# Concurrent Modification Exception after setting all test project to work in parallel SpringBoot and junit

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit4

Running all the java tests takes so much time to finish.

So the solutions is to run all the tests in parallel using multiple threads to run functions using `@RunWith(ParallelSuite.class)` in all classes.

But the problem is that there is some functions when they run in parallel they use the same resources. So it throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`. The solutions is to set this functions and to run them sequentially.

How to isolate some function to work sequentially after configuring all junit test in a spring boot project to work in parallel using ParallelSuite otherwise is there any other solution for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `synchronized` for functions that need to be accessed by one thread at a time or you can do within a single function using :

```
void runSync() {
    synchronized (this) {
        count = count + 1;
    }
}
```

You probably also should read [this](https://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples/).